# Chemistry context in Mathematica 13

Tags: chemistry

Version: 13.0.1 on Linux

Hello,
I am curious about the Chemistry` context in Mathematica. I noticed some new things; however, there doesn't seem to be documentation on them. I wonder if anyone here has tried some of these things, or if there is a resource somewhere.

```
Needs["Chemistry`"]
Chemistry`MoleculeDissimilarity
Chemistry`TemplateReaction
```

Thanks,

Comment: I think these will be added in 13.1. You can follow the development in Language Design series of Live CEOing: [Ep. 584](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0TjmL1j9aCk), [Ep. 579](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1NWH2Vo7yn0), [Ep. 576](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fYqpc3_ekqE), [Ep. 521](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XSO4my8mTs8) ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "Chemistry`" context contains mostly internal functions used by the built-in System [Chemistry functionality](https://www.wolfram.com/language/core-areas/chemistry/).  These functions are undocumented and may change from version to version.

A new and documented context has been created for extra chemistry functions - from minor utilities that don't quite belong in the System context to prototype functions that may some day become part of the language.  The [ChemistryFunctions paclet](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/WolframChemistry/ChemistryFunctions/) is now available from the Wolfram Language Paclet Repository.

To install the paclet use

```
PacletInstall["WolframChemistry/ChemistryFunctions"]
```

To load the paclet in a kernel session use

```
Needs["WolframChemistry`ChemistryFunctions`"]
```

Doing this will make [all of the functions](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/WolframChemistry/ChemistryFunctions/guide/WolframChemistryFunctions.html) in the paclet available.

Some of the interesting functions include [StereoisomersQ](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/WolframChemistry/ChemistryFunctions/ref/StereoisomersQ.html), [MoleculeManipulate3D](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/WolframChemistry/ChemistryFunctions/ref/MoleculeManipulate3D.html), [AtomSelector](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/WolframChemistry/ChemistryFunctions/ref/AtomSelector.html), and [EmpiricalFormula](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/WolframChemistry/ChemistryFunctions/ref/EmpiricalFormula.html).  New functionality will be added regularly.

Comment: (+1) Does Wolfram U offer any courses dedicated to chemistry using Mathematica?